# Safari & Chrome Giving diffrent results to the same script (document.querySelector)

Tags: javascript, hugo

Why are Safari and Chrome giving different results when using document.querySelector in the same script?

What I'm trying to do is display the image next to the link when hovering over it. The image should be displayed next to the link.
In Safari, the image is displayed properly from the left corner, but in Chrome, when I scroll down and point at the link, the image is displayed from unexpected angles.

JavaScript:

```
let attached = false;

function showImage() {
  const image = document.querySelector('img');
  if (image && !attached) {
    attached = true;
    image.style.display = 'block';
    document.addEventListener('pointermove', function(event) {
      image.style.left = event.x + 'px';
      image.style.top = event.y + 'px';
    });
  }
}

function hideImage() {
  const image = document.querySelector('img');
  if (image && attached) {
    attached = false;
    image.style.display = 'none';
    document.removeEventListener('pointermove', function(event) {
      image.style.left = event.x + 'px';
      image.style.top = event.y + 'px';
    });
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
  img{
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 640px;
    height: auto;
  }
```

I've tried changing the code to:

````
let attached = false;

const getElmtImage = (elmt) => {
  return elmt.querySelector("img")
}



const followMouse = (elmt, event) => {
  elmt.style.left = event.x + "px";
  elmt.style.top = event.y + "px";
}

function showImage(elmt) {
  const image = getElmtImage(elmt)
  if (!attached) {
    attached = true;
    image.style.display = "block";
    document.addEventListener("pointermove", function(event) {
      followMouse(image, event)
    });
  }
}

function hideImage(elmt) {
  const image = getElmtImage(elmt)
  attached = false;
  image.style.display = "none";
  document.removeEventListener("pointermove", followMouse);
}```
````

Comment: It's not particularly clear what you're asking, but – assuming there's only one `<img>` on the page, and that you have `showImage` and `hideImage` as the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event handlers on some link element – I'd expect your code to show the image next to the cursor position when the user hovers over the link. There is a problem however with your use of `removeEventListener` – you need to remove the exact same function object that was used with `addEventListener`; perhaps you could store that in `attached`.

Answer (score 0):

I have conducted some testing, and it appears that Chrome and Safari handle events differently (based on my testing, although I could be mistaken). In Safari, event.x works, whereas in Chrome only event.pageY works. To work around this issue, I first check the browser type and then execute the appropriate functions. This approach may not be the cleanest, but it is effective. If you have a better idea of how to handle this situation, please share it.

```
let attached = false;

var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
if (ua.indexOf('safari') != -1) { 
  if (ua.indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
    // chrome
    function showImage() {
      const image = document.querySelector('img');
      if (image && !attached) {
        attached = true;
        image.style.display = 'block';
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
          image.style.left = event.pageX + 'px';
          image.style.top = event.pageY + 'px';
        });
      }
    }
    
    function hideImage() {
      const image = document.querySelector('img');
      if (image && attached) {
        attached = false;
        image.style.display = 'none';
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
          image.style.left = event.pageX + 'px';
          image.style.top = event.pageY + 'px';
        });
      }
    }  } else {
      // safari
    function showImage() {
      const image = document.querySelector('img');
      if (image && !attached) {
        attached = true;
        image.style.display = 'block';
        document.addEventListener('pointermove', function(event) {
          image.style.left = event.x + 'px';
          image.style.top = event.y + 'px';
        });
      }
    }
    
    function hideImage() {
      const image = document.querySelector('img');
      if (image && attached) {
        attached = false;
        image.style.display = 'none';
        document.removeEventListener('pointermove', function(event) {
          image.style.left = event.x + 'px';
          image.style.top = event.y + 'px';
        });
      }
    }  }
}
```